# Packaging drawable resources with a JAR?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I've built a semi-push service (checkins for notifications from a centralized http server) that I'd like to distribute to a few friends and customers, so they can easily add push-like notifications to their apps without much hassle.

I've gotten far enough to package the JAR and include it in a few of my other projects, but now I'm hitting a brick wall with regard to resource packaging --

- In my PushNotify project, I have a resource: R.drawable.goldstar
- I draw it twice in the application, once by referencing `R.drawable.goldstar`, and once by referencing `resources.getIdentifier('goldstar', 'drawable', 'com.com.pushnotify')`
- When I package PushNotify as its own APK, the gold star correctly appears in both places.
- I right click in eclipse, Export Project, as JAR file, un-check "ApplicationManifest.xml" from included files, and click "Finish".
- I can verify that the size of this JAR file increases when I add more drawable resources.
- When I then package DependantApp.apk, including PushNotify.jar in the build path, the gold star correctly appears in both places.
- If I uninstall PushNotify.apk, the gold stars disappear from DependantApp.apk as if they were not packaged with the JAR; a 0 value is returned for `getIdentifier('goldstar', 'drawable', 'com.com.pushnotify')`.

How can I distribute a JAR with drawable resources, and have them appear in the dependent apps? Apps including my JAR never need to access the icons I am distributing, only my own code does.

Despite much nay-saying on in the search results I find, **I am certain this is somehow possible**, because a) my JAR file grows when I add new images, and b) I've included JAR files that come with icons before (**Airpush does this, as does UrbanAirship**).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I distribute a JAR with drawable resources, and have them appear in the dependent apps?

That is not presently supported. Creating Android library projects that can distribute resources is on the tools roadmap and will hopefully come out in the not-too-distant future.

Comment: I have consumed JAR files that do exactly what I am talking about. Please read my last paragraph.

Comment: @linked: What you are doing is not presently supported. The only supported means of distributing resources as part of a reusable component is the Android library project. And those cannot be directly packaged as JARs. "At this time, library projects containing the jar file directly instead of the source code are not yet supported." (http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14) And while that document indicates that R15 was supposed to add support for this, it did not, nor did R16.

Comment: @linked: While there are rough workarounds, none involve the resources actually being in the JAR at the present time. It is not even clear to me whether resources-in-the-JAR is part of what the Tools team is planning on doing, though I certainly got that impression. Java has had its own "resources" construct for longer than Android, and it supported stuff in JARs, but you would not be accessing them via `R.` constants -- despite the same names, "resources" in Android bear no relation to "resources" in the old Java style.

Comment: @linked: My best guess, therefore, is that the JAR files you cite are using the old Java resources (and therefore will have challenges when it comes to differing screen densities, etc.). Whatever you are doing with the project-export-as-JAR has never been supported, where by "supported" I mean "it is commonly known what will happen, is documented, etc.".

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer (and followup). I am frustrated that this appears to be the most correct information available at this time, but you appear to be right. I will commence banging my head against the wall until the Android team decides to implement what I want, or maybe I will send a patch upstream ;) Until then, I guess I'm sending out .zip files. Cheers!

Comment: What about now? Is packaging resources in jars still not supported?

Comment: @RavitD: Correct. The new Gradle-based build system supports packaging Android library projects as AAR files, which do contain resources.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is possible in the way you are trying to do that. Android "builds" recources inside its apks. Resources in jar files are (as far as I know) ignored.

You could However build it as an "android-library" where these xml layouts are included. If you don't want the whole code "easyly readable" you could put only this rescources and the classes that are using them inside the "android-library" while the rest inside your library stays inside the .jar file

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you were asking for but here is an interesting option anyway :

Instead of `getIdentifier('goldstar', 'drawable', 'com.com.pushnotify')` use `getIdentifier('goldstar', 'drawable', getApplicationContext().getPackageName())`

And distribute the images/resources as a .zip to be unzipped, installed and compiled with the target app (the one that will use your shared .jar)

And don't include the images in the .jar.

This is not tested but that should work.